# Implement insertion sort in c++ using Stack or Queue?

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

Classical insertion sort algorithm with array is

```
void insertion_sort (int arr[], int length){
        int j, temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && arr[j] < arr[j-1]){
              temp = arr[j];
              arr[j] = arr[j-1];
              arr[j-1] = temp;
              j--;
              }
        }
}
```

So should it implemented by using stack or queue?

Comment: I'd be curious how you think you would do that.

Comment: It's not possible to sort with a single stack. It is possible to sort with a single queue with something like bubble sort, using O(1) space to hold a single element. With 2 stacks, something like bubble sort can be implemented. With 2 queues or 3 stacks, a bottom up merge sort can be used. In the case of 3 stacks, a polyphase bottom up merge sort is faster, but more complicated. Because ordering is reversed when moving data from stack to stack, the program needs to keep track if it should be doing ascending or descending sequences, adding to the complication.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a vector, you gain the performance that all the memory you're working with is contiguous, but lose performance because you have to copy.
If you use a linked list of any type, you gain because you don't have to copy, but you lose because your memory is scattered all over the place.

As such, this will depend on the number of items being sorted, the processor cache, and probably a whole host of other things.

Given that this sorting algorithm is known to be slow for any numbers of N, the correct solution is to not worry about performance at all and just use std::sort.